# The set of all nonempty and convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector space...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples

...where the addition and scalar multiplication is defined as $A+B=\{a+b|a\in A \ and \ b\in B\}$ and $\alpha . A = \{\alpha a | a \in A\}$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

I think this claim is false, since $A=[0,1]$ and $-A=[-1,0]$ are convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ but $A+(-A)\neq {0}$. Is my reasoning correct?

Is it possible to create a vector space with intervals or non-discrete sets?

Thank you in advance for any tip and advice.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.  - You can make the powerset of $\Bbb R$ a vectro space over $\Bbb F_2$, with symmetric set difference as addiiton

Comment: Note the study of infinite dimensional vector spaces is called Functional Analysis, if you want to look more into it

Comment: You might first want to verify that, with respect to this addition, the zero element is the nonempty convex subset $\{0\}\subset\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct, though you might first want to verify that the zero element with respect to this addition is the nonempty convex subset $\{0\}\subset\Bbb{R}$.

Then it is indeed the case that
$$A+(-A)=\{a+a':\ a\in[0,1],\ a'\in[-1,0]\}\neq\{0\},$$
because $1+0=1$ and $0+(-1)=-1$ are elements of $A+(-A)$, but not of $\{0\}$.

**Edit:** As noted in the comments, you might also want to verify that no other nonempty convex subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is the inverse of $A$, i.e. no other nonempty $B\subset\Bbb{R}$ satisfies
$$A+B=B+A=\{0\}.$$
Of course $A\subset A+B$ so all convex nonempty subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ fail to have an inverse, except $\{0\}$ itself.

Alternatively, if the set is a vector space then multiplication distributes over addition and so
$$A+(-A)=1\cdot A+(-1\cdot A)=(1+(-1))\cdot A=0\cdot A=\{0\},$$
which we have just shown to be false.

Comment: You'd probably need to confirm that no other set can be the negation of $[0,1]$ as well. (An easy cardinality argument)

Comment: Though I suppose that is taken care of by the definition given for multiplication.

Comment: @Chessanator You are right on both points, I implicitly argued from assuming distributivity. I have edited to clarify. This thing clearly fails to be a vector space on many points.